# Return Bulk data using webService

Tags: apex, soap, apex-webservice

I am writing a SOAP WS in salesforce to return data from multiple objects

```
global class TXLIDAWS {

webservice static List<DataWrapper> GettxlidaData(){
    List<DataWrapper> dataWrapperList = new List<DataWrapper>();
    Set<Id> includedFindingReviews = new Set<Id>();

    //from QC review finding, query all Parent object, get Data, make a wrapper class and return
    for(QC_Review_Finding__c QC : [select id,Weighting__c,comments__c,QC_Review_Criterion__c,QC_Review_Finding_Section__c,QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Application_Number__c,QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Final_Reviewer__r.Name,QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Initial_Reviewer__r.Name,QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Program__c,QC_Review_Criterion__r.Case_Development_Section__c,QC_Review_Criterion__r.QC_Review_Section__r.Section_Number__c from QC_Review_Finding__c where QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Program__c='TX LIDA' LIMIT 50000]){
        DataWrapper wrapper = new DataWrapper();
        wrapper.applicationNo = QC.QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Application_Number__c;
        wrapper.finalReviewer  = QC.QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Final_Reviewer__r.Name;
        wrapper.initialReviewer  = QC.QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__r.Initial_Reviewer__r.Name;
        wrapper.comments = QC.Comments__c;
        wrapper.weighting = QC.Weighting__c;
        wrapper.casedevelopmentsection = QC.QC_Review_Criterion__r.Case_Development_Section__c;
        wrapper.sectionNo = QC.QC_Review_Criterion__r.QC_Review_Section__r.Section_Number__c;
        dataWrapperList.add(wrapper);

        includedFindingReviews.add(QC.QC_Review_Finding_Section__r.QC_Review__c);
    }

    //if any QC review does not have child, get its data also.
    for(QC_Review__c QC : [select id,Application_Number__c,Final_Reviewer__r.Name,Initial_Review_Complete_Date__c,Initial_Reviewer__r.Name,Final_Review_Complete_Date__c from QC_Review__c where Program__c='TX LIDA' and Id NOT IN :includedFindingReviews]){
        DataWrapper wrapper = new DataWrapper();
        wrapper.applicationNo = QC.Application_Number__c;
        wrapper.finalReviewer  = QC.Final_Reviewer__r.Name;
        wrapper.initialReviewer  = QC.Initial_Reviewer__r.Name;
        dataWrapperList.add(wrapper);
    }
    return dataWrapperList;
}

global class DataWrapper{
    webService String initialReviewer;
    webService String finalReviewer;
    webService String applicationNo;
    webService String comments;
    webService Decimal weighting;
    webService String casedevelopmentsection;
    webService Decimal sectionNo;
}

}
```

Now if the reocrds in less than 50K then its works fine. But i Have around 300k records. How can i return them using this WS??